# JAVA_HOME not defined correctly

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperserver, java-home

I am attempting to update Jasper Reports Server, and having an issue with Java. It uses Tomcat to run java. I did not install java on this server, and I am not very familiar with java. Java was installed in a folder called `/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.0.0/apache-tomcat/java/bin/`. I do not believe Java was installed correctly, and it is telling me that the `JAVA_HOME` is not defined correctly.

> We cannot execute /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.0.0/apache-tomcat/java/bin/java

Java is located in that directory.

I ran the following in a bash shell:

```
export JAVA_HOME=”/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.0.0/apache-tomcat/java”
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Can you please help me on what I am doing wrong when setting the `JAVA_HOME`, or does it have something to do with the java folder? should I reinstall Java altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the file /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.0.0/apache-tomcat/java/bin/java exists, right ?

Can you execute it ? Can it execute standard jar file ?

Comment: ouch - had the wrong directory. I realized it when I put your directory in. Apologize for the time waste!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you do not have execute permission for anything inside the `$JAVA_HOME` path.

You should try using `chmod` to give execute permission (atleast to `bin/java` ) , though I would just give to all files. Example -

```
chmod -R +x /path/to/<folder>/
```

or for a single file

```
 chmod +x /path/to/file
```

also, can you please try the `export JAVA_HOME` without the double quotes and check -

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.0.0/apache-tomcat/java
```

Comment: I checked that earlier, and everyone has rights to execute all the files in that directory.

Comment: And what you have updated is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Above the line is: "Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. We cannot execute...

Comment: What is the shell you are using - is it `bash` or `csh` or `ksh` ?

Comment: bash - the response is coming from an installation file js-upgrade-newdb-ce.sh. It has the right folder

Comment: updated the answer, can you please try the export JAVA_HOME without the double quotes